# Dynamically creating the related_name from META class

Tags: python, django, django-models

Most of my Django models use the same User Mixin, because of this I would like to dynamically create the `related_name` for the field.

I would like it to be the class name where `TestModel` becomes `test_models` or maybe even a set name from the meta class on the main model.

I have looked at `self__class__.__name__` but this give me the name of the User class.

**Would it be possible to do something like below, if so how....**

```
class User(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(USER, related_name=META.related_name)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class TestModel(User):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=80)

    class Meta:
        related_name = "test_model"
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think it might be sufficient to handle this like it is [documented here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name).

```
# myapp/models.py
class User(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        USER, 
        related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related"
    )

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class TestModel(User):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=80)
```

This way the related name would dynamically become **`myapp_testmodel_related`**. Of course you can tweak the name and simplify the pattern, if it is certain that the names can't clash between multiple apps.

Comment: What does the character "s" before app_label and class depict ??

Comment: @shivam returns the lowercase name of those variables.